# CakePHP: Show 404 if post doesn't exist or direct them to correct post

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the following view method on my CakePHP site for showing portfolio items:

```
function view ( $id, $slug )    
{   
    $post = $this->Portfolio->read(null, Tiny::reverseTiny($id));

    $this->set(compact('post'));
}
```

This expects a url such as: http://driz.co.uk/portfolio/3z/Paperview_Magazine

However http://driz.co.uk/portfolio/3z/ will also show the post and http://driz.co.uk/portfolio/3z/Fake_Text will also too!

Not only that totally bogus urls like http://driz.co.uk/portfolio/Random_Text will just show a blank screen but still use the view 'View'

1.) How can I make sure that the slug is correct and enforce that one is appended on the url in addition to the id. I've seen on some sites such as Forrst they just redirect the user to the correct post so if they miss the slug or mistype it, it just corrects itself e.g. the post http://forrst.com/posts/Simple_pure_CSS_tooltip_with_arrow-BkY could also be accessed at http://forrst.com/posts/Simple_pure_CSS_tooltip_and_extra_text_added_to_url_arrow-BkY

2.) How do I show a 404 for bull urls like http://driz.co.uk/portfolio/Random_Text

THANKS

Answer (score 1):

**Answer 1:**
You could likely achieve this by using a [beforeRender, beforeFilter](http://book.cakephp.org/view/984/Callbacks) or [afterFind](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1048/Callback-Methods) perhaps. This would involve taking the submitted slug, passing it to your model, checking if it is valid, and perform any additional logic as required. If it passes, then show the content, otherwise redirect/whatever.

> However http://driz.co.uk/portfolio/3z/ will also show the post and http://driz.co.uk/portfolio/3z/Fake_Text will also too!

If you are certain your `view` method will only ever take two parameters; you can do this:

```
function view($id, $slug, $bogus=null) {

    if($bogus) {
        $this->cakeError('error404');
    }
    // carry on as normal.
}
```

Essentially, if there is a 3rd URI segment, then we can assume it's a *bogus* URL (although it would still display fine, as your method uses the `$id`, so this isn't *necessary* in my opinion.

To prevent `portfolio/Random_text` from occuring, you would need to check that the parameter is valid - so in your case it should be numeric as you are using an `$id`. You should then check this against your database, and if a result is found display it, otherwise, do not.

There are likely other solutions.

Also; IMO it probably isn't worth worrying too much. If anyone wants to screw with the URL's you're better off just 404'ing them, rather than trying to resolve their own mess for them. My 2cents at least!

Comment: How would I 404 them if they came across a bogus url then?